# How can I easily diff dependencies between two Maven pom files?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

My boss likes for the dependencies in a given Maven pom file to be sorted by scope, group, and artifact ID.

I've recently inherited a fair number of projects with a fair number of dependencies that were not sorted. So I sorted them.

Long story short, I want to make sure I did not inadvertently drop a dependency or copied in the wrong sorted dependency into the wrong pom.

So I was wondering if there was some sort of mechanism or Maven report plugin that will diff a pom with a previous version and show me what dependencies were added or modified.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: any SCM have this feature : "compare with previous version..."

Comment: Yup. SCMs are awesome for those kinds of things except for when the text is rearranged as I described above.  It would be cool if there was such a thing as a smart differ.

Comment: Sorta.  I was hoping for a more automated approach.  Basically if I do mvn dependency:tree, I'd have to do it for both the old and new version and then diff.  That's assuming that mvn dependency:tree has a deterministic order independent of the order in the pom itself.

Comment: I'm sorry @Michael.  While I'm grateful for the assistance, I do not believe this is what I'm looking for.  I'm familiar with mvn dependency:tree.

As a follow up to this question: eventually I discovered an in house proprietary plugin that does what I wish.  If it ever gets released to the open source world, I'll be sure to link it here so that others who have the same need to diff releases' dependencies can do that easily.  Or if someone else discovers something that does the same thing, I'll gladly accept that as the correct "answer".

Comment: Hey @JasonThompson, any update to the Open Source story? :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like to use a simple [script](https://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/) to get a sorted list of dependencies and then compare them with a difftool like meld.

```
#!/bin/bash
# first grab all dependencies
mvn dependency:resolve >/dev/null

# then list them with -o to keep noise low,
# remove extra information and duplicates
mvn -o dependency:list \
| grep ":.*:.*:.*" \
| cut -d] -f2- \
| sed 's/:[a-z]*$//g' \
| sort -u
```

Answer (score 10):

Maven plugin - [version](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/compare-dependencies-mojo.html), might rescue you.

```
mvn versions:compare-dependencies -DremotePom=my.group:other-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I love to simplify by filtering, sorting and print only unique differences for nested multiple modules. To do that use:

```
   mvn versions:compare-dependencies -DremotePom=my.group:other-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT | grep '\->' | sort | uniq
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: This plugin only compares and shows jars with versions updated. If you intend to find the new jars as well, this would not cut it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve dependencies issues in Maven is the following command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: To expand on this, I had a similar issue where I had to ensure that two projects had the same dependencies. I found that the easiest way to do this was by running:

`sdiff <(mvn dependency:tree -f ~/projectOne/pom.xml) <(mvn dependency:tree -f ~/projectTwo/pom.xml) | less`

Side by side, nice and easy to read, it was immediately obvious to me which dependencies where missing and needed to be added.

Comment: For me a simple side-by-side comparison wasn't feasible since the dependencies didn't have the same order.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way (for me) to do this was to use the eclipse 'Effective POM' view.

This is how to do it

1. Open the first pom in eclipse.
2. Click on the 'Dependency Hierarchy' tab for that pom.
3. Open the second pop in eclipse.
4. Click on the 'Dependency Hierarchy' tab for that pom.
5. Drag the second pom window out of eclipse to create a second eclipse window so that you can view the pom dependencies side by side.

Hope this helps :)